# MSBuild GetPathOfFileAbove() returning empty

Tags: msbuild

I am trying to refactor the code below to use GetPathOfFileAbove() instead.

```
<Import Project="$([MSBuild]::GetDirectoryNameOfFileAbove($(MSBuildThisFileDirectory),global.json))\eng\Configurations.props" />
```

when i tried the below code, an error was thrown, file not found

```
 <Import Project="$([MSBuild]::GetPathOfFileAbove('global.json','$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)'))\eng\Configurations.props" />
```

The path of the above code result in,where "global.json" shouldn't have been here:

```
"C:\dotnetruntime\runtime\global.json\eng\Configurations.props"
```

Expected path:

```
"C:\dotnetruntime\runtime\eng\Configurations.props"
```

I having a hard time finding documentation to figured out the configuration am missing here. Can you guys  give me some pointers

Comment: aren't you supposed to use `dotnet` with CORE? (not `msbuild`)

Comment: @T.S edited the tag, and updated the question

Comment: you need to supply project file header and version of VS. And which file are you modifying. Is this a proj file or some global file?

Comment: This is wrong: `'global.json','$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)'))\eng\Configurations.props`

Comment: what is the expected path?

Comment: @T.S vs 2019 and am modifying a .props file which will be imported by tests projects

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/property-functions?view=vs-2017

Comment: @T.S. question updated to add expected path

Comment: @T.S. already had a look at the doc, can't seem to be able to figure it out thought

Comment: Try `Configurations.props, $(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)`

Comment: @T.S. i get this error now  error MSB4019: The imported pr
oject "C:\eng\Configurations.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and th
at the file exists on disk.

Comment: This is it. the syntax is correct. Now you need to make sure you hit correct directory

Comment: @T.S. this is the final part, how do i tell the msbuild to search only the repo i have and not go till C drive root folder

Answer (score 1):

The correct path to use was

```
"<Import Project="$([MSBuild]::GetPathOfFileAbove(Configurations.props,$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)))../../../../../eng/Configurations.props" />"
```

The use of "../" allows the file be searched one directory above.